# AttributeError: 'Language' object has no attribute 'lang_proficiency'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

My models look like these :

**first have user profile**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """user profiling """
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    languages = models.ManyToManyField('Language', through="UserLanguage")
```

**then have a language many to many relation**

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**then have a through table to store this data**

```
class UserLanguage(models.Model):
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class ProficiencyStatus(models.TextChoices):
        FLUENT = 'FL', _('FLUENT')
        CONSERVATION = 'CT', _('CONSERVATIONAL')

    lang_proficiency = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=ProficiencyStatus.choices,
        default=ProficiencyStatus.FLUENT,
    )
```

now issue is when I am inserting data in this table like :

```
language_obj = Language.objects.create(name=language.get('name'))
user_lang_obj = UserLanguage.objects.create(language=language_obj,
                                                            user_profile=user_profile, lang_proficiency='FL')
   
user_profile.languages.add(language_obj)
```

I am getting error like:

**AttributeError: 'Language' object has no attribute 'lang_proficiency'**

**EDIT:**
My serializer is like this

```
class LanguageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    lang_proficiency = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = UserLanguage
        fields = ('name', 'lang_proficiency')
```

And my payload for language is like this :

```
"languages" :[{"name":"arabic" ,"lang_proficiency":"FL"},{"name":"english","lang_proficiency":"FL"}],
```

Comment: You've already created the UserLanguage object and that means the many to many relationship is created too, no need to call `user_profile.languages.add`

Comment: @IainShelvington thanks for replying . now I am getting this error :::   `AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `lang_proficiency` on serializer `LanguageSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Language` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Language' object has no attribute 'lang_proficiency'`

Comment: @IainShelvington I think issue is in serilazier . I have updated question